# Multiple Counting Buttons JS

Tags: javascript, css, html

I'm trying to create something a page that creates post so every time someone clicks a button it creates a text with another button to like. I want each separate like button to be incremented upon clicking but it doesn't work. Either only one count is updated or none. I'm using HTML5 and CSS with javascript.

```
$(function(){
$('.input_button').on('click', function(){
    text = $('.input_text').val();
    var btn = document.createElement("BUTTON");
    var t = document.createTextNode("Like");

    btn.appendChild(t);
    document.body.appendChild(btn);
var clicks = 0;
    btn.onlick = function() {
        clicks += 1;
    document.getElementById("clicks").innerHTML = clicks;
    };
    if (text != undefined) {
        post = '<div class="post test--post">' + '<img src="photo.JPG" width="20" height="25" alt=""/>' + '<p><span>jaleelg: </span></p>' + text + 
        '<p>Clicks: <a id="clicks">0</a></p>' + "<br>" + Date() + " " + '</div>';
        new_post = $('.post_feed').append($(post)) 
        new_post = $('.post_feed').append($(btn)) 
    }
});
```

});

Comment: Some code, please... Have you actually tried anything?

Comment: yes i added the code

Comment: Did you get any errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were a bunch of things wrong with the code, but I fixed them: https://jsfiddle.net/yak613/opoy49ox/

```
$(function(){
$('.input_button').on('click', function(){
    text = $('.input_text').val();
    var btn = $("<button></button>");
    btn.text(text);
    $("body").append(btn);
    btn.after("<span class='clicks'></span>")
    var clicks = 0;
    btn.click(function() {
        clicks++;
        $(this).next(".clicks").html(clicks);
    });
    if (text != undefined) {
        post = '<div class="post test--post">' + '<img src="photo.JPG" width="20" height="25" alt=""/>' + '<p><span>jaleelg: </span></p>' + text + 
        '<p>Clicks: <a id="clicks">0</a></p>' + "<br>" + Date() + " " + '</div>';
        new_post = $('.post_feed').append($(post)) 
        new_post = $('.post_feed').append($(btn)) 
    }
});
});
```

Comment: This overrides the first count every time one of the new button counts is clicked. I had something similar in one of my trials. I need each button to have it's own count.

Comment: works in the link but not in the complete code but thank you very much I guess it's just my error now! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

this is how to make a button:

```
**function onClick() {
    clicks += 1;
    document.getElementById("clicks").innerHTML = clicks
<body>



<button type="button" onClick="onClick()">Click Me!</button>



<p>clicks: $<a id="clicks">0</a></p>



</body>**
```